# Asker unaccepted my answer after I rejected asker's edit to my answer

Tags: discussion, answers, unaccepted-answer

[Here is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38837421/simple-way-to-plot-time-series-with-real-dates-using-pandas) I am referring to. I answered the question, and then some more. Note that the question only pertained to the date column, which `pandas` automatically converts to the correct format by inferring the format of the date. However, I realized that the asker would run into problems because the data was in the European format (which used commas for decimal points, and decimal points as thousands separator). So (if you follow the comments below the answer) I edited my question to include two methods to convert the data into the English format that would allow conversion to floats and make the data plottable.

The two methods I suggested were string replacement and using the locale package. The OP liked the `locale` package but could not get it to work. I tried my best to suggest things that OP could do, but eventually OP dismissed the answer as not workable (please review the edit history and comments under the answer). I presented a complete working example in my answer, which the OP then edited to remove the use of locale package, and only include the string replacement method.

I did not think it fair that an entire method that the OP could not get to work was removed from the answer, when it could help another with a similar problem. I rolled back the OP's edits, and then edited my answer a little to clean it up. The OP retracted the answer accept today, and I can only assume it was because I did not keep the OP's edits.

## TL;DR

My answer still answers OP's question, and the OP has verified that the answer works. I can also verify that the answer works. However, the OP unaccepted the answer because the OP's edits to the answer were not accepted. How does one deal with a situation like this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The accepted answer checkmark is entirely the asker's prerogative, just like each user's up and down votes. Just move on.

Comment: Is it not in the interest of SO as a whole that questions have accepted answers?

Comment: @Kartik you can find in places that bad answer (even some which are downvoted to one of the planes of Oblivion) are accepted while non accepted answer are up-voted to have much higher scores than accepted answers. the true test of an answer isn't which has a tick by it (because that's only worth 15 rep) but how many people found it useful/helpful outside the asker and thus upvoted it themselves which is [VOTES] x 10 rep and 2 upvotes from other people trumps whatever the asker thinks with their pissy accept vote

Comment: At least I know that my answer covers all methods to do what was asked. I am going to adapt it into `pandas` documentation here on SO.